# How to disappear or hide my sencha touch 2 native web app on ipad 4 when user click my "cancel" button

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I don't want to kill my app , I just want to my app disappear after user click the "cancel " button in the login page . I want the effect is same as users click the "home " key on the ipad like other native app . I make my web app by sencha touch 2.2 and build it as native app by phonegap.com  or sencha touch cmd tool on Mac .
Any idea ?
thanks again